# The result is differed for same formula in conditional format and normal cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In attached excel sheet, the cell `P11` has the below formula in conditional format rule.

Actual formula: `=AND($B8="Med Risk",H$5>=$E8,H$5<=$E8+$F8-1)`.
Conditional format formula for `P11` cell is:  `=AND($B11="Med Risk",H$5>=$E11,H$5<=$E11+$F11-1)`

```
B11---> Med Risk
H5--->  7/8/2019
E11---> 7/15/2019
F11---> 4

B11="Med Risk" ---> True
H5>=E11 --->    False
H5<=E11+F11-1 --->  True
Final result will be ---> False
```

When the above is used directly in any cell, it gives result `FALSE`. But it gives result as `TRUE` when it is used as conditional format formula for a cell. So that `P11` cell is filled with format (violet) color.
Please let me know, what actually happening here for both cases? 
If above formula gives result as `False` always, why the conditional format is applied in `P11` cell?

Please help me to understand this.

Excel sheet link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rd9yOAcmy0ZyTDkOO3TgHAed7tVdvLfy/view?usp=sharing

Thanks,

Comment: The first formula is referencing different cells, can we see those inputs as well? Because right now while the formula is the same, the inputs may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly!

When relying on the formula you had provided, the result is false. However, in reality, at `P11`, the formula that conditional formatting is calculating would be `=AND($B11="Med Risk",O$5>=$E11,O$5<=$E11+$F11-1)`

```
B11="Med Risk" ---> True

O5>=E11 --->    True

O5<=E11+F11-1 --->  True
```

Final result will be `True`.

Since there is no "`$`" in front of the "`H`" in your formula, it will change columns in the formatting array.